# My Goerli wallet has been drained

Tags: wallets, security, hack

I want to open [this question from overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308884/someone-transferred-my-faucet-without-my-permission) since it was closed and I experience the same problem.

This account "0x87C02eeacB08c11aFBb821798DB2F4cCcd8F9E3d" has been stealing many goerli and main net accounts. Example of goerli transaction:

- [0xeb15b92d543becb7170b30a111d00059dd5e96519640a49cc0b6cd64591f21c5](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xeb15b92d543becb7170b30a111d00059dd5e96519640a49cc0b6cd64591f21c5)

my machine is Linux ubuntu desktop and I have my disk encrypted. I need a pointer how to find security hole in my system. Also need to use this as placeholder for victims of the same EOA or similar nature

Comment: How did you generate the private key for the `0x13AeB3c8D30fb1a69F32736688af68D49582E3CF` address. Did you generate it yourself or did you use an (default) account generated by `hardhat`, etc. Did you ever put the PK into .env file and pushed it to github?

Comment: the most common problem is you are using an exposed seed phrase or a not real - or very old version of metamask. phrases from hardhat, ganache, and some other old tools are not random and can be recalculated

Comment: If you need G-Eth give me the public key of a *not compromised* private key or seed phrase and I can send you 2 when I have time.

Comment: I generate my PK from metamask. I put it in .env but never push it to github.

Comment: are you using `vim` and pushed an `env.swp` file?

Comment: no I didn't use vim nor push env.swp

Comment: I am a beginner solidity developer and I wanted to comment that I also had my Goelri ETH drained by this address ending in "9e3d" 7 days ago. I also generated my wallet using Metamask. I've stored the seed phrase as a note in Lastpass and am concerned that the recent compromise of Lastpass has caused the compromise of my seed phrase, however, my other wallets linked to that seed phrase have not been drained. Here is the address of the wallet that has been drained: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x0483FC9D40BABB2a0EB5C788C1496dbD92e781DE

Comment: similar issue occured for me too
'0xA266b6dbAaa9805C8D2D77370c7b3EC227A600E4' took goerli ethers from my account.
Transaction Hash:0x0303450366bfb4ac3cf6b4fa8cce62c35158cacdcc58b109204083525cb13975
even there were few ether,collected those few daily with 0.1 each day
Any way to stop this?